# The third book of The Godslayer series by James Clemens

Tags: godslayer

Is there official word from [the author](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Clemens), or his publisher, regarding the release of the third book in the [*Godslayer* series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?18281)? The [second book](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?373741) was published in 2006, at least in the UK, so there's been quite a wait for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2008 he said the third book was [planned](http://fantasybookcritic.blogspot.com/2008/06/last-oracle-by-james-rollins-wbonus-q.html), and would be followed by another trilogy. [In 2009 he said](http://www.sffworld.com/forums/showthread.php?s=e43c1f9f05a190a00c2ecffa4de0342a&t=16847&page=2) "The Godslayer series has had some work but nothing planned this or next year."

He's been busy writing under his other pen-name, "James Rollins".